# How to upgrade symfony/phpunit-bridge to use PHPUnit 7?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.2 with test-pack which includes symfony/phpunit-bridge 4.2.

The default version of PHPUnit is 6.5, but I want to upgrade it to 7.5.

On the Symfony PHPUnit Bridger doc, it says:

> Set the SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION env var to e.g. 5.5 to change the base
>   version of PHPUnit to 5.5 instead of the default 5.3.
>
> It's also possible to set this env var in the phpunit.xml.dist file.

I tried three ways:

1. Set **SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION** in the **phpunit.xml/phpunit.xml.dist** file in the project root folder.
2. Set **SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION** in **.env.test** file.
3. Set **SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION** to 7.5 in the **/bin/phpunit** file.

And then, I removed the /bin/.phpunit folder and ran /bin/phpunit command to reinstall the PHPUnit.

Only the 3rd way worked on upgrading the PHPUnit version.

What have I done wrong here?

Where is the best place to set SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and stumbled across your post, thanks for your hint with this env var.

In my case, I put the **SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION** into my docker-compose.yml to my container environment definition.
It was not necessary to delete the bin/.phpunit folder because re-running **bin/phpunit** takes care that the required version is installed.

If you don't use docker you could could try this:

```
SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION=7.5 bin/phpunit
```

or

```
export SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION=7.5
bin/phpunit
```

Comment: I think it's the same with the 3rd method I mentioned. Just wonder if there're other methods without using docker, and why the other two methods don't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Basically yes but modifying a third-party file is never a good practice. In Your case I would create a makefile which calls phpunit with your desired version.

Comment: Yup, I know what you mean. bin/phpunit is not in the vendor folder, it's created by phpunit-bridge, so I think it's fine to change it, but I still think it's better to put all the configurations to one file like .env or .env.test.

Comment: FYI. Found these support tickets: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28726, https://github.com/symfony/recipes/issues/476

Comment: While the docker-compose env works as a solution, I still think this is a bug and reported it as such on Symfony https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/31816